# recordmydesktop becomes invisible

Tags: recordmydesktop, kazam

After starting recordmydesktop and clicking 'record' the window with recordmydesktop disappears. And so I can not stop it.
With Kazam I had the same problem.

I installed the program as root and use it as a user with limited rights.

The recordmydesktop window disappears completely. It disappears from the taskbar also.

Comment: I don't use this but it seems to me it would disappear to not obstruct your desktop while recording ? Try pressing ctrl + H, based on this http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/rug/app_a.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but ctrl + H does not work.

Answer (score 3):

have you had a look at the taskbar (or whatever this is called in Ubuntu)? I mean the place at the top right of your desktop, where you also have access to sound, power options and so on. Once you start recording, a small red icon appears (on the unity desktop). Clicking this, you can choose to pause or stop the recording.

Comment: I do not see this red icon when using Gnome Desktop 3.34.2.